# ArcGIS Flex API: Keep info window on top of other widgets?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am working on a web mapping widget using the ArcGIS flex API and ArcGIS Flex Viewer.  I have a infoWindow popup when there is a mouse rollover on a map graphic.  Problem: the infoWindow renders below other widgets which obscures the data in the info window. Is there a way to force the info window to render on top of all the other viewer widgets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thread in the ESRI Flex Viewer forum where I explain why this is not possible

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/54004-Make-InfoWindow-popup-open-to-the-left-or-on-top-of-widget...